# CodeMaid usage : how to Setting 'readonly static' to 'static readonly'. (Visual Studio 2022 )

Tags: visual-studio-2022, codemaid

This is a question regarding Visual Studio 2022.
When I cleaned up the source with the extension CodeMaid, I converted readonly static to static readonly.
Where can I configure this setting?

I can't find this setting at CodeMaid options.